# Rough noise while accelerating

Tags: engine, nissan

My car is a 2002 Nissan Altima with 106,873 miles. After 95K miles, my car has been giving a rough noise from the engine. After shifting into second gear, it's smooth until I hit the gas pedal hard.

Another issue is that...I hear a noise from the engine when my car is idle and the A/C is switched on. When I change it to neutral, it's quiet and calm.

I had some oil burning issues with the car when I bought it at 85k Miles.

Comment: How long ago were the timing belts replaced (these are the rubber belts at the front of your engine that operate the valves as well as other features like water pump, power steering and air con. These should be replaced perhaps every 60K miles or so, so maybe yours are old?)

Comment: I don't think they have been replaced. Any idea on how much that would cost?

Comment: For all of them probably around $1000 (maybe a bit less). If you want to save cash you could just get the main essential belts replaced and not worry too much about the ones that power the aircon/power steering. I'm not sure this would be your propblem though - just a guess

Answer (score 1):

My car had a similar symptom. It turns out the exhaust was blowing. Look for holes and bad rust along your exhaust lines and also look at the exhaust manifold in the dark while revving the engine. A lot of times you'll be able to see the holes "spark".